# Como remover o ponto após o número no marcador?

Tags: html

Como eu removo esses pontos no marcador que é exibido após o número do item de uma lista ordenada:

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lista 1</li>
  <li>Lista 2</li>
  <li>Lista 3</li>
  <li>Lista 4</li>
  <li>Lista 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Felipe, sugiro que você primeiramente leia https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs para se adequar à comunidade SOpt.

Comment: Você quer remover somente o ponto, mantendo assim a numeração?

Comment: @DanielMendes, sim!

Comment: Acredito que não existe esse estilo (de apenas números) por padrão no html, segundo o [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-type_all)

Comment: Pois é... Remover somente o ponto, utilizar o ```list-style-type: none;``` vai remover tudo, ponto e numeração, mas só conheço isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para retirar o ponto após a numeração do item é um processo um tanto complicado mas é possível fazê-lo. Utilize o código CSS abaixo, isso irá tirar o ponto do número do jeito que deseja:

```css
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li { 
    display: block; 
}

li:before { 
    content: counter(item) "  "; 
    counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Lista 1</li>
  <li>Lista 2</li>
  <li>Lista 3</li>
  <li>Lista 4</li>
  <li>Lista 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hum! Bacana! :D